# Unicode regex does not work

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string: `"asdf"`
And it is not recognized by this regex: `^[\p{L}]{3,32}$`. As far as I know, the `\p{L}` should match any unicode letter. Why doesn't it? When i replace it with A-Za-z it works fine, but i need unicode characters. How can i fix this?

Comment: This works perfectly ([link](http://ideone.com/s6cQsM)). You didn't forget to double the slash, did you? It wouldn't compile otherwise... You do not need square brackets around `\p{L}` unless you need to add more characters to the class.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: There is also literal string in C# starts with `@` that doesn't need to double the slash. http://ideone.com/gtbO5t

Comment: @dasblinkenlight -ur input string is wrong! it should have been `"\"asdf\""`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Double slash works perfectly, thanks!
And yeah i got `@` before my regex and still, i needed to use doubleslash.

Comment: @AppDeveloper I doubt it, I think the OP used quotes for clarity. After all, `[A-Za-z]` worked for him, right?

Comment: @ojek I guess now is a good time to delete the question :) **EDIT:** Oops, too late, you've got an answer...

Comment: @ojek: Check this link: http://ideone.com/gtbO5t

Answer (score 0):

```
// [\p{L}]{3,32}

// A character with the Unicode property “letter” (any kind of letter from any language) «[\p{L}]{3,32}» Between 3 and 32 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{3,32}»
```

By definition : `"` is not a letter in any of the language!

Try this Regex : `^"[\p{L}]{3,32}"$`

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("\"asdf\"", "^\"[\\p{L}]{3,32}\"$"));  //True
    }
}
```